# Swift Decoder, trying to decode file with layers

Tags: swift, decoder

How would I decode this json file with JSONDecoder().decode

```
{
  "text": "pear",
  "parsed": [
    {
      "food": {
        "foodId": "food_bq6stkiaxkwhxia9q4v7wanjnew0",
        "label": "Pear",
        "nutrients": {
          "ENERC_KCAL": 57,
          "PROCNT": 0.36,
          "FAT": 0.14,
          "CHOCDF": 15.23,
          "FIBTG": 3.1
        },
        "category": "Generic foods",
        "categoryLabel": "food",
        "image": "https://www.edamam.com/food-img/65a/65aec51d264db28bbe27117c9fdaaca7.jpg"
      }
    }
  ],
  "hints": [
    {
      "food": {
        "foodId": "food_bq6stkiaxkwhxia9q4v7wanjnew0",
        "label": "Pear",
        "nutrients": {
          "ENERC_KCAL": 57,
          "PROCNT": 0.36,
          "FAT": 0.14,
          "CHOCDF": 15.23,
          "FIBTG": 3.1
        },
        "category": "Generic foods",
        "categoryLabel": "food",
        "image": "https://www.edamam.com/food-img/65a/65aec51d264db28bbe27117c9fdaaca7.jpg"
      },
      "measures": [
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_unit",
          "label": "Whole",
          "qualified": [
            {
              "qualifiers": [
                {
                  "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Qualifier_large",
                  "label": "large"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "qualifiers": [
                {
                  "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Qualifier_small",
                  "label": "small"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "qualifiers": [
                {
                  "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Qualifier_medium",
                  "label": "medium"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_serving",
          "label": "Serving"
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_half",
          "label": "Half"
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_slice",
          "label": "Slice"
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_gram",
          "label": "Gram"
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_ounce",
          "label": "Ounce"
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_pound",
          "label": "Pound"
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_kilogram",
          "label": "Kilogram"
        },
        {
          "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Measure_cup",
          "label": "Cup"
        }
```

The file goes on and on.

I try to do [String] but it says it expects a dictionary,
So I put in a dictionary, then it says it expects another dictionary,
This repeats until I have this:

```
let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String: [String: [String: String]]].self, from: data!)
```

Then I get the error

> "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Though when I go back one to do a string/data I get this error

> "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Help?

Comment: Drop this into https://app.quicktype.io and it'll write the Decoder for you. The point of Decodable is to create structs, not a dictionary of strings. (It *can* create Dictionaries if you actually have JSON with an arbitrary set of keys, but that's not what you have here. You have structured JSON, so you should create structs to hold the result.)

Comment: We recommend to use Codable. The issue is that once parsed, the JSON is not a `[String: [String: String]]`, for instance, there is `"text": "pear",`, so is a `[String: String]`, but you said you were expecting a `[String: [String: String]]`. You have in fact a `[String: Any]`, where `Any` is sometimes a `String` (for `"pear"`), an array for the `hint` key: `[{"food": ... }]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use a [quick parser](https://app.quicktype.io/), however
you need to understand why is this happening, the issue here is that you're passing `[String: [String: [String: String]]]` which is not valid skeleton for this key you can start breaking down each layer alone to understand first level for example `[String, Any]` and then start exporting each key and decode that stand alone, using the above link your models should be something like that.

```
// MARK: - Foo
struct Foo: Codable {
    let text: String
    let parsed: [Parsed]
    let hints: [Hint]
}

// MARK: - Hint
struct Hint: Codable {
    let food: Food
    let measures: [Measure]
}

// MARK: - Food
struct Food: Codable {
    let foodID, label: String
    let nutrients: Nutrients
    let category, categoryLabel: String
    let image: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case foodID = "foodId"
        case label, nutrients, category, categoryLabel, image
    }
}

// MARK: - Nutrients
struct Nutrients: Codable {
    let enercKcal: Int
    let procnt, fat, chocdf, fibtg: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case enercKcal = "ENERC_KCAL"
        case procnt = "PROCNT"
        case fat = "FAT"
        case chocdf = "CHOCDF"
        case fibtg = "FIBTG"
    }
}

// MARK: - Measure
struct Measure: Codable {
    let uri: String
    let label: String
    let qualified: [Qualified]?
}

// MARK: - Qualified
struct Qualified: Codable {
    let qualifiers: [Qualifier]
}

// MARK: - Qualifier
struct Qualifier: Codable {
    let uri: String
    let label: String
}

// MARK: - Parsed
struct Parsed: Codable {
    let food: Food
}
```

And you can use it simply like this:

```
let foo = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: jsonData)
```